# How to control flow without .flatMap, which breaks a reactive stream preventing operators like distinctUntilChanged from working on the entire stream

Tags: rx-java, kotlin, reactive-programming, rx-java2, algebraic-data-types

I want to handle a different observable chain of logic for different implementations of `State`. This can easily be achieved with a sealed class/algebraic data type/union + `.flatMap()`, but this breaks the stream, where operators like `.distinctUntilChanged()` only work within the `.flatMap()` function, not on the *whole* stream itself.

```
sealed class State {
    object Loading : State()
    data class Loaded(val value: Int) : State()
}

@Test fun distinctTest() {
    val relay = PublishRelay.create<State>()
    relay.flatMap {
        fun handle(state: State): Observable<*> = when (state) {
            State.Loading -> Observable.just(state)
                    .distinctUntilChanged()
                    .doOnNext { println("loading") }

            is State.Loaded -> Observable.just(state)
                    .distinctUntilChanged()
                    .doOnNext { println(it.value) }
        }
        handle(it)
    }
            .subscribe()

    relay.accept(State.Loading)
    relay.accept(State.Loaded(1))
    relay.accept(State.Loaded(2))
    relay.accept(State.Loaded(3))
    relay.accept(State.Loaded(3))
    //desired: loading, 1, 2, 3
    //actual: loading, 1, 2, 3, 3
}
```

Note, this is a simplified example. While I’m just printing here, I actually want to perform different actions (render the UI differently) based on the implementing type of `State`

This can be accomplished with a subject/relay, but but that would create a disconnected, mutable stream, which I would also like to avoid.

Comment: Great question mate!

Comment: have you considered moving `distinctUntilChanged` next to `relay`: `relay.distinctUntilChanged.flatMap...` ?

Comment: @m.ostroverkhov definitely, but that's not my use case. need `distinctUntilChange` to work on the whole stream. your suggestion has `distinctUntilChanged` not operating within the flatmap. having both would be too expensive of an operation in my use case

Comment: What if you try using `distinctUntilChanged(BiPredicate<? super T, ? super T> comparer)` instead of the empty one, and create a `BiPredicate` object in which the `test()` method returns the comparison between the two objects (based on the int value)?

Answer (score 1):

Could you split the `Observable` into multiple observables with each of them getting events of a single type? You could then perform some operations on these observables, before merging them back together again.

I am not able to test this right now, so it may need some tweaks. Anyway, I hope you get the idea here:

```
@Test fun distinctTest() {
    val relay = PublishRelay.create<State>()

    val loadingObs = relay.filter { it is State.Loading }
                          .distinctUntilChanged()
                          .doOnNext { println("loading") }

    val loadedObs = relay.filter { it is State.Loaded }
                         .distinctUntilChanged()
                         .doOnNext { println(it.value) }

    val merged = loadingObs.mergeWith(loadedObs)

    merged.subscribe()

    relay.accept(State.Loading)
    relay.accept(State.Loaded(1))
    relay.accept(State.Loaded(2))
    relay.accept(State.Loaded(3))
    relay.accept(State.Loaded(3))
    // Hopefully prints this: loading, 1, 2, 3
}
```